# Tomcat filter for enabling HPKP

Tags: java, security, tomcat, https, http-headers

I am trying to enable HPKP certificate pinning in our app's tomcat server. I added a filter to include the HSTS and HPKP directives. I am getting the HSTS and HPKP directives in the response header as expected.

But even after I change the certificate in the server or intercept the request and send a fake certificate, browser does not stop the request. Browser is HPKP capable as it is blocking other HPKP enabled sites like facebook when the request is intercepted and presented with a fake certificate.

Just wondering if there is anything wrong the way I am generating the hash of the public key and hence browser is not pinning the key? Any feed back if anyone has enabled HPKP for tomcat?

Filter added in web.xml

```
    <filter>
            <filter-name>HttpsSecFilter</filter-name>
            <filter-class>com.x.x.x.x.x.HttpsSecurityFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>HttpsSecFilter</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>..[url-pattern]..</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
```

Filter code (Modified to include only relevant parts for brevity)

```
public class HttpsSecurityFilter implements Filter {
    private boolean _isHTTSEnabled = false;
    private long _httsMaxAge = -1;

    private boolean _isHPKPEnabled = false;
    private long _hpkpMaxAge = -1;
    private String _hpkpCertHashesString = null;

    private boolean _includeSubdomains = false;

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
                FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {

        if (_isHTTSEnabled && response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Strict-Transport-Security", 
                                                       "max-age=" + _httsMaxAge);
        }

        if (_isHPKPEnabled && response instanceof HttpServletResponse) {
            ((HttpServletResponse) response).setHeader("Public-Key-Pins", 
                                                       _hpkpCertHashesString);
        }

        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig arg0) throws ServletException {
        //Read from application configuration file
        _isHTTSEnabled = true;
        _httsMaxAge = 5184000;

        _isHPKPEnabled = true;
        _hpkpMaxAge = 5184000;
        _includeSubdomains = false;

        if (_isHTTSEnabled) {

            try {
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
                InputStream is = new FileInputStream(APP_HOME + "/conf/keystore");
                keyStore.load(is, keysotrePassword);
                is.close();

                Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate(myappcetificatealias);

                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                byte[] digest = md.digest(cert.getPublicKey().getEncoded());
                _hpkpCertHashesString = "pin-sha256=\"" + java.util.Base64.getEncoder()
                                        .encodeToString(digest) + "\"; max-age=" + 
                                         _hpkpMaxAge;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Directives from response header

```
Public-Key-Pins:pin-sha256="JdZ3itf02UwsCav0X26wcSQLGfo="; max-age=5184000
Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=5184000
```

Answer (score 0):

The Public Key Pinning Extension for HTTP (HPKP) is a security feature that tells a web client to associate a specific cryptographic public key with a certain web server to decrease the risk of MITM attacks with forged certificates.

Unfortunately Apache Tomcat does not support HPKP filter. So we have to write our own 'Global filter', Valve.
First you need to extract the public key information from your certificate or key file and encode them using Base64.
The following commands will help you extract the Base64 encoded information from a key file, a certificate signing request, or a certificate.

```
openssl rsa -in my-rsa-key-file.key -outform der -pubout | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64

openssl ec -in my-ecc-key-file.key -outform der -pubout | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64

openssl req -in my-signing-request.csr -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64

openssl x509 -in my-certificate.crt -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

The following command will extract the Base64 encoded information for a website.

```
openssl s_client -servername www.example.com -connect www.example.com:443 | openssl x509 -pubkey -noout | openssl pkey -pubin -outform der | openssl dgst -sha256 -binary | openssl enc -base64
```

Example HPKP Header

```
Public-Key-Pins: 
  pin-sha256="cUPcTAZWKaASuYWhhneDttWpY3oBAkE3h2+soZS7sWs="; 
  pin-sha256="M8HztCzM3elUxkcjR2S5P4hhyBNf6lHkmjAHKhpGPWE="; 
  max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains; 
  report-uri="https://www.example.org/hpkp-report"
```

In this example, pin-sha256="cUPcTAZWKaASuYWhhneDttWpY3oBAkE3h2+soZS7sWs=" pins the server's public key used in production. The second pin declaration pin-sha256="M8HztCzM3elUxkcjR2S5P4hhyBNf6lHkmjAHKhpGPWE=" also pins the backup key. max-age=5184000 tells the client to store this information for two months, which is a reasonable time limit according to the IETF RFC. This key pinning is also valid for all subdomains, which is told by the includeSubDomains declaration. Finally, report-uri="https://www.example.net/hpkp-report" explains where to report pin validation failures.
Now create a Valve as described below.
Create a Maven Java Application.
Add the following dependency:

```
<dependency>  
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId> 
<artifactId>catalina</artifactId>    
<version>6.0.53</version>    
<scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

- Create your Java class and extend it from ValveBase.
- Implement the invoke(Request, Response) method.

  ```
  public class GlobalFilterValve extends ValveBase {

      @Override
      public void invoke(Request request, Response response) throws IOException, ServletException {
      response.setHeader("Public-Key-Pins", "pin-sha256=\"cUPcTAZWKaASuYWhhneDttWpY3oBAkE3h2+soZS7sWs=\"; pin-sha256=\"M8HztCzM3elUxkcjR2S5P4hhyBNf6lHkmjAHKhpGPWE=\"; max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains");               
      getNext().invoke(request, response);
      }

  }
  ```
- Build your library (.jar) file
- Copy the jar file in the    ${tomcat.home}/lib directory.
- Configure the server.xml to use your    new valve. For example:

> ```
> <valve className="org.devan.GlobalFilterValve"/>
> ```

- Start the server to see    your new valve in action

Thank you !

Answer (score -1):

Try to update `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/website.conf`
or `/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`

```
Header set Public-Key-Pins "pin-sha256=\"JdZ3itf02UwsCav0X26wcSQLGfo=\"; max-age=5184000; includeSubDomains
```

Comment: He asked for tomcat not apache2